# модуль sys отказывается принимать аргументы

Tags: python

При попытке присвоить аргумент (захватить объект с помощью sys)

```
import sys

var_1 = sys.argv[1]
var_2 = sys.argv[2]
print(var_1, var_2)
```

Неизменно выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python.Trials\convert\convert.py", line 5, in <module>
    var_1 = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

При этом, видит только нулевой аргумент (sys.argv[0]), указывая, естественно, на сам файл-скрипт, а вот никакой иной объект захватывать не желает.  Проблема имеет место как в PyCharm, так и в более "скромном" PyScripter...
ps Операционная система Windows 10

Comment: Ну так а вы аргументы-то вообще передали скрипту?

Comment: В этом проблема!  Командная строка видит каталог, где находится файл-скрипт, но аргументы не принимает. ввожу так:                                                                    "C:\Python.Trials\PDF_Processing>python script_name.py  file_1.pdf  file_2.pdf" затем Enter и командная строка просто возвращается в своё исходно значение    "C:\Python.Trials\PDF_Processing>"  без каких-либо изменений.

Comment: Скрипт в вопросе и скрипт в комментарии называются по-разному и лежат в разных папках. Вы уверены, что не попутали файлы и запускаете правильный скрипт?

Comment: Нет, точно нет. Просто в комментарии я уже привел пример аналогичной проблемы на другом файле.